# C++ auto conversions

Tags: c++

For two unrelated classes "class A" and "class B"
and a function

```
B convert(const A&);
```

Is there a way to tell C++ to automatically, for any function that takes "class B" as argument, to auto convert a "class A".

Thanks!

Comment: If you cannot change the class definitions for either class A or class B there is no good way to do this.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

What you would normally do in this case is give `B` a constructor that takes an `A`:

```
class B
{
public:
    B(const A&);
};
```

And do the conversion there. The compiler will say "How can I make `A` a `B`? Oh, I see `B` can be constructed from an `A`".

Another method is to use a conversion operator:

```
class A
{
public:
    operator B(void) const; 
}
```

And the compiler will say "How can I make `A` a `B`? Oh, I see `A` can be converted to `B`".

Keep in mind these are very easy to abuse. Make sure it really makes sense for these two types to implicitly convert to each other.

Comment: I second the warning concerning implicit conversion operators. During the last ten years, whenever I was tempted to introduce such a thing (with the exception of a string class I once wrote), sooner or later it turned out to kick in when nobody expected it and was thus removed from the code - often at quite a cost. Also keep in mind that the compiler will always only ever invoke exactly _one_ user-defined conversion. So if there's also a user-defined conversion from `B` to `C`, you cannot call `void f(C)` with an `A`, because that would require two conversions.

Answer (score 1):

You can supply a cast operator, or a one-parameter constructor.